I want to mint seed bird NFt and its giving me this response, "unable to interact with the contract address" on okx , how do I resolve it please
On Okx web3 wallet, I want to mint seed bird NFt, and I get this response
Unable to interact with contract address please try again later '
Please show me how to overcome this

idk maybe try a new rpc
